nginx 1.24.0 w/tls termination pcap
Running nginx 1.24.0 as a container on alpine.  It's performing TLS termination for our backend endpoints on a single network interface.  Performing a tcpdump to produce a PCAP to troubleshoot an errant connection yields nothing but encrypted data -- somewhat understandably.
I say somewhat because the proxy connection should be unencrypted data as nginx sends it to the backend service but I'm not seeing plaintext data at the packet level.  Unfortunately I can't dump on the backend service in this case (like I have in other cases to see that there is plaintext).
Is there a way to tcpdump in nginx to see the decrypted packet-level data to my back-end services?
EDIT (proxy_host cfg example):
server {
  set $forward_scheme https;
  set $server         "x.x.x.x";
  set $port           443;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name my.fqdn.com;

  # Custom SSL
  ssl_certificate /mnt/secrets-store/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /mnt/secrets-store/cert.key;

  # Force SSL
  include conf.d/include/force-ssl.conf;

  # Logging
  error_log /data/logs/ccp_error.log warn;

  location / { 
    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }

  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}

EDIT (proxy.conf):
add_header       X-Served-By $host;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_pass       $forward_scheme://$server:$port$request_uri;


"Performing a tcpdump to produce a PCAP" - if nginx is a HTTPS reverse proxy for a
plain HTTP backend then there will be an enrypted connection to nginx (as a server) and an unencrypted connection from nginx (as a client to the backend). So either you sniff the wrong connection (details about setup and how you capture are missing) or you interpret unencrypted data as unencrypted since they are binary (images or compressed traffic - again, no details known what you really see).

@SteffenUllrich -- I"m just doing a tcpdump -ni eth0 host x.x.x.x -s 65535 -w .  nginx only has a single interface... so I'm unclear as to why I'm not seeing the plaintext side.

What is the nginx configuration, specifically what gives proxy_pass as backend? You need to capture the traffic to the backend and only this. "nginx only has a single interface" - these is probably also the loopback device, which might be the one used to communicate with the backend (if http://127.0.0.1:port or so). Again, it is still not clear enough how the system is configured and what you are doing.

@SteffenUllrich, So I dumped on the "lo" interface and saw no traffic.  I was always under the impression this was used for local-only traffic.  Regardless, I added one of my proxy_host cfgs and proxy.conf if that helps.

Based on the config you send the traffic to the backend as https, not as plain HTTP (forward_scheme https). If "the proxy connection should be unencrypted data" as you write, then you have to configure it for plain http, not https.
